# Moment.js duration days error

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm doing a count down with moment.js and duration to return days, hours, minutes and seconds. So, when I use moment.duration with miliseconds, it return a non-sense days...

```js
var miliseconds = 4423852000
var divided = miliseconds / 1000 / 24 / 3600 // return: 51,20 days (correct)
var duration = moment.duration(miliseconds).days() // return: 20 days (???)

document.querySelector('.days').innerHTML = divided
document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = duration
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.js"></script>

<pre class="days"></pre>
<pre class="result"></pre>
```

I'm using moment.duration correctly??

Comment: RTM: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/

Comment: _"I'm using moment.duration correctly??"_ - If you're unsure, read the documentation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`asDays()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/) instead of [`day()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/):

> As with the other getters for durations, `moment.duration().days()` gets the days (0 - 30).
>
> `moment.duration().asDays()` gets the length of the duration in days.

```js
var miliseconds = 4423852000
var divided = miliseconds / 1000 / 24 / 3600 
var duration = moment.duration(miliseconds).asDays()

document.querySelector('.days').innerHTML = divided
document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = duration
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.js"></script>

<pre class="days"></pre>
<pre class="result"></pre>
```