# Countdown based on timezone with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, moment-timezone

I worked with this:

```js
(function() {

  var timeElement, eventTime, currentTime, duration, interval, intervalId;

  interval = 1000; // 1 second

  // get time element
  timeElement = document.querySelector("#countdown");
  // calculate difference between two times
  eventTime = moment.tz("2022-05-29T08:00:00", "Europe/Berlin");
  // based on time set in user's computer time / OS
  currentTime = moment.tz();
  // get duration between two times
  duration = moment.duration(eventTime.diff(currentTime));

  // loop to countdown every 1 second
  setInterval(function() {
    // get updated duration
    duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');

    // if duration is >= 0
    if (duration.asSeconds() <= 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      // hide the countdown element
      timeElement.classList.add("hidden");
    } else {
      // otherwise, show the updated countdown
      timeElement.innerText = duration.days() + ":" + duration.hours() + ":" + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds();
    }
  }, interval);

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.17/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>

<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Unfortunately, the time doesn't get calculated correctly. If you change for example `2022-05-29` to `2022-08-29`, nothing changes. Additionally, every value should have two digits.

Has someone an idea to fix that? Would be very thankful!

Comment: use asDays() instead of days() https://stackoverflow.com/a/49260792/903014

Comment: see string.padStart() `duration.seconds().toString.padStart(2, 0)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question about `momentjs` is answered here; [use asDays() not days()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49260792/903014)

You can pad a string with 0's using the function `padStart(length, withWhat)`  [Mozilla Developer Network Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```
//...snip...
    } else {
      // otherwise, show the updated countdown
      timeElement.innerText =
        duration.asDays().toFixed().padStart(2, 0) + ":" +
        duration.hours().toString().padStart(2, 0) + ":" +
        duration.minutes().toString().padStart(2, 0) + ":" + 
        duration.seconds().toString().padStart(2, 0);
    }
//...snip...
```